# Setting the value of a $scope variable which is in a included template in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a very simple setup as given below. My problem is, of the two variables that i set from within the success call back of $http, one reflects in UI while the other doesnt.

As you can see im trying to show the progress when the controller loads, and hide it after the success callback executes. But it doesnt work as the false i set in the success call back doesnt seem to propogate to the UI.

> messages.html

```
<div>
<div ng-include="'partials/common/progress.tpl.html'"></div>
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

> progress.tpl.html

```
<div ng-show="{{showProgress}}"  class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
```

> controller

```
app.controller('MessageController',['$scope','$http','ROOT_URL','$q',
  function($scope,$http,ROOT_URL,$q) {
    $scope.showSkipBtn = "false";
    $scope.title = "Message of the Day";    
    $scope.showProgress = "true";    
    $http.get(ROOT_URL+'get_message_for_the_day').then(function(result){
      $scope.message = result.data.message_of_the_day.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>');    
      $scope.showProgress = "false";
      console.log($scope.showProgress);
    });            
}])
```

Comment: `ng-show` evaluates the expression you pass to it and hides the element if the expression evaluates as truthy. The string `"false"` is truthy (as well as the `"true"` you have). You're probably looking to use the boolean `false` and `true`

Comment: @Ian I think you're right, but you need to make this an answer and not a comment. Then it can be voted on, and it helps others see in a list of questions, what has answers, and what has been successfully answered.

Comment: @JohnMunsch Actually, I'm wrong. The answer that was just posted seems to be correct. I'm not sure why, but I didn't think strings "true" and "false" would work. Simply removing the `{{}}` (which I meant to include in my comment to, now that I see it), fixes the problem, without using boolean true and false

Comment: As a suggestion though, use booleans, not strings, for things evaluated like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In progress.tpl.html remove curly braces which surrounds showProgress